# How to get Beats per minutes of a song in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I did lots of R&D but did not get any good answer. I am working on music type app in iphone and i have to categorized songs on the basis of beats per minute.So my first task to find out BPM of song.How can we do that? I got some answers like:
1.using MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute property of MPMediaItem class ,will it work fine. I have doubt on this because some guys said it will return null.
Do you have any sample code or logic to get this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out answer of phix23 in this link on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250918/access-bpm-field-on-a-song-mpmediaitempropertybeatsperminute-not-working

Comment: That's only R that you've done. The D is for development, in which you check it out by prototyping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://www.un4seen.com/ for detecting BPM of song.

Here is code for calculating BPM using this library.

```
HSTREAM mainStream = BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE,[pathStr UTF8String],0,0,BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT|BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN|BASS_STREAM_DECODE);

float playBackDuration=BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds(mainStream, BASS_ChannelGetLength(mainStream, BASS_POS_BYTE));

HSTREAM  bpmStream=BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, [pathStr UTF8String], 0, 0, BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN|BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT|BASS_STREAM_DECODE);

float BpmValue= BASS_FX_BPM_DecodeGet(
                                bpmStream,
                                0.00,
                                playBackDuration,
                                MAKELONG(45,256),
                                BASS_FX_BPM_MULT2,
                                 NULL);


    //Check if BpmValue have any value or not.
    //If it haven't any value then set default value to 128.
    if(BpmValue<=0)
          BpmValue = 128.00;
```

You can do many other things like scratching using this library.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to understand the link, but which of those products will do that for iPhone in Objective-C?

Comment: @Yar : Yes, You can use that library for iPhone projects. **BASS is available for the Win64, WinCE, iOS, and Android platforms.**

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that while I was looking right at it.

Comment: Hello Devang, Did you use this api and do you have any objective-c code where we have a music file and getting all passing parameters in this function. if you have something else please share asap.

Comment: At http://www.un4seen.com/ you will find forum where you will get many sample codes. And Calculating BPM, I am using above code.

Comment: Hello Devang, I used this api and check some mp3 files but always it's giving bpm -1 in negative. Is something wrong or it's problem related to audio files.

Comment: I have pasted code below this one:BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_IOS_MIXAUDIO, 0); // Disable mixing. To be called before BASS_Init.

Comment: @NarendraKumar : **You have to edit your code in your question.** and check my updated answer.

Comment: hey how are you calculating for mainStream, i did this one:mainStream=BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, [respath UTF8String], 0, 0, BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);

Comment: Try This : mainStream = BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE,[pathStr UTF8String],0,0,BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT|BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN|BASS_STREAM_DECODE);

Comment: sorry dude i m getting BpmValue 0 in all cases.share ur email id i will send you my code and you can check it.

Comment: hello sir, how can we get absolute path of music file from document directory? I am using this but getting problem :NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *respath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mixer.wav"];

Comment: @Devang can u please link the documentation for BASS?

Comment: @AceNeerav : Its pretty much old answer. I dont remember it now...sorry

Answer (score 1):

Get Bpm of audio songs within minute:

```
BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_IOS_MIXAUDIO, 0); // Disable mixing. To be called before BASS_Init.

if (HIWORD(BASS_GetVersion()) != BASSVERSION) {
    NSLog(@"An incorrect version of BASS was loaded");
}

// Initialize default device.
if (!BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, NULL, NULL)) {
    NSLog(@"Can't initialize device");

}

//NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""

NSString *respath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"[Songs.PK] Paathshaala - 01 - Aye Khuda" ofType:@"mp3"];

DWORD chan1;
if(!(chan1=BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, [respath UTF8String], 0, 0, BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP))) {
    NSLog(@"Can't load stream!");

}

mainStream=BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, [respath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], 0, 0, BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT|BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN|BASS_STREAM_DECODE);

float playBackDuration=BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds(mainStream, BASS_ChannelGetLength(mainStream, BASS_POS_BYTE));
NSLog(@"Play back duration is %f",playBackDuration);
HSTREAM bpmStream=BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, [respath UTF8String], 0, 0, BASS_STREAM_PRESCAN|BASS_SAMPLE_FLOAT|BASS_STREAM_DECODE);
//BASS_ChannelPlay(bpmStream,FALSE);
BpmValue= BASS_FX_BPM_DecodeGet(bpmStream,0.0,
                                 playBackDuration,
                                 MAKELONG(45,256),
                                 BASS_FX_BPM_MULT2,
                                NULL);
NSLog(@"BPM is %f",BpmValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides [aurioTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) sample code which display the input audio in one of the forms, a regular time domain waveform, a frequency domain waveform (computed by performing a fast fourier transform on the incoming signal), and a sonogram view (a view displaying the frequency content of a signal over time, with the color signaling relative power, the y axis being frequency and the x as time).

Comment: New link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html