# Get BPM of audio track in Spritekit

Tags: swift, audio

I am trying to find a way to get the BeatsPerMinute (BPM) of an audio file saved within the X-code Swift Project? Any help is appreciated!  Incase you're wondering, the overall aim of the project involves running a function on the beat of a track.

Comment: An advice: try to add some of your code to better understand what do you want to achieve, for example if you use AVAudioPlayer or other..

Comment: I haven't got any code yet, the company I work for has planned a project which would require this kinda code, and as the iOS developer it's my responsibility

Comment: It's a simple task, look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696748/how-to-get-beats-per-minutes-of-a-song-in-objective-c

Comment: I am using Swift @AlessandroOrnano

Comment: So? What's the problem? You can translate the code..

Comment: Check some code you think it can be good, try to translate it to swift and report in your question the part of this code where you have some problems in translation

Comment: Which answer are you referring too on that post? @AlessandroOrnano

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9697032/1894067, you're lucky, the BASS library is updated to XCode7, you can also create a Objective C class copy and paste the answer code with the BASS library included and import objc to swift

Comment: the BASS library project download is blank, this is a weird library,have you used it previously? @AlessandroOrnano

Comment: If you cannot download BASS library from official site, try on GitHub, for example here https://github.com/Alterplay/APAudioPlayer

Comment: that Git page doesn't mention BPM at all? @AlessandroOrnano